# ¿Cómo hacer que FilesystemIterator sea más rápido?

Tags: php, html

Estoy haciendo una aplicación con php y html que busca imágenes en un directorio de la PC, implementé FilesystemIterator y funciona, solo muy lento ya que el directorio tiene más de 3,500,000 imágenes, ¿cómo puedo hacerlo más eficiente?

Estaba usando glob () demasiado lento, y DirectoryIterator me da un resultado muy similar a FilesystemIterator.

```
<?php
  $filename = '00232431.001'.'.jpg';
  foreach (new FilesystemIterator('//10.168.10.134/pegaso/IMAGENES/') as 
  $fileinfo) {
      if($fileinfo->getFilename() == $filename){
       echo $fileinfo->getFilename() , PHP_EOL;
      }
  }
?>
```

Espero que el resultado sea el nombre del archivo y si lo muestra solo con este error "Error fatal: Tiempo de ejecución máximo de 30 segundos excedido en C: \ xampp \ htdocs \ viewer \ visor.phpon línea 41" y es muy lento.

Comment: ¿El script solo sirve para saber si existe un archivo con ese nombre?

Comment: así es, estoy realizando un buscador.

Comment: ¿Has intentado con [`is_file`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.is-file.php)? Por que no veo que busques si el nombre del archivo contiene la cadena

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Y por qué no utilizar directamente `file_exists()` sin tener que recorrer el directorio entero, cosa que no tiene sentido si solo quieres saber su un archivo existe en ese directorio.

Ejemplo

```
$filename = '00232431.001'.'.jpg';
$path = '//10.168.10.134/pegaso/IMAGENES/';

if( file_exists($path . $filename) ) {
    echo $filename;
} else {
    echo 'No existe el fichero';
}
```

Comment: _"`file_exists` — Comprueba si existe un fichero o directorio"_. En cambio _"`is_file` — Indica si el nombre de fichero es un fichero normal"_, un detalle a tener en cuenta. Yo no cree un respuesta porque me da la sensación de que no es exactamente lo que esta necesitando.

Comment: @Marcos bien visto. Sinceramente tampoco me queda claro a donde quiere llegar el OP. Ni en esta ni en la otra pregunta. Pero un bucle de 3.5M de iteraciones como tiene no creo que sea lo más apropiado.